# Some Unicode Emoji get clipped / distorted for Font-Size above 256px

Tags: html, css, unicode, emoji

Apparently certain combinations of emoji and font-size, result in the emoji itself not rendering or rendering in a clipped/distorted fashion.

Yet its text-shadow, if set, will render correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/0x2gqfyc/

```
<div style = "display:flex; flex-direction:column; gap:32px">

<div style = "display:flex; flex-direction:row; gap:32px">

    <div style = "display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; font-size:300px; text-shadow: 2px 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);">
    
    </div>

    <div style = "display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; width: font-size:256px; text-shadow: 2px 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);">
    
    </div>

    <div style = "display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; font-size:258px; text-shadow: 2px 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);">
    
    </div>
    
</div>

<div style = "display:flex; flex-direction:row; gap:32px">

    <div style = "display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; font-size:300px; text-shadow: 2px 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);">
    
    </div>

    <div style = "display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; font-size:257px; text-shadow: 2px 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);">
    
    </div>

    <div style = "display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; font-size:258px; text-shadow: 2px 6px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);">
    
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Tested on Chromium/Chrome/Edge 99.
Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround?

(Font-Size limit being 2^8 pixels is kind of suspicious, but perhaps it's just a coincidence?)

Screenshots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3mbe.jpg

Comment: Many emoji implementations use bitmaps

Comment: Which still doesn't explain the weird rendering behavior you can see exhibited in the fiddle

Comment: I am on WIndows10 Edge on a laptop and don't see any problem with the large emoji, it seems to be being rendered complete. What system are you on? And perhaps you could include a screenshot so we can see the problem?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fJvrAGb    Windows 11.   Same happens on Windows 10 machine. However, on a Windows 10 VM I just tested, it doesn't

Comment: It’s possible that there’s a text rendering shift when you use the shadow. You might consider opening a bug with Chromium

Comment: @DanielA.White I intended to, but couldn't find anything to submit a rendering bug. Templates are all about javascript and UI

Comment: Perhaps it’s the blink project

Comment: Update: now being investigated https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1303466#c3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome fonts developer here, this sounds like https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1280180 which is fixed in Chrome M100. Could you retest in Chrome M100, available as Beta version?

Comment: Solved on Edge/Chromium V100 on Windows 11